# How can I get these bones to import with the rest of the armature?

Tags: armature, bones, import, .fbx

I have an FBX file that I want to import into Blender, including several meshes, an armature, and animations.  My problem is that the character's eyes and weapon are disconnected from the mesh and the armature upon import.

I checked the armature using Noesis, and here's what I found:

[image]

That's a list of bones in the armature.  The regularly-named ones (Bone042, Bone043, etc.) all import, display, and animated correctly.  The bones numbered 162 and 163, or "eyes" and "weapon," respectively, don't import at all.

The meshes that should be assigned to these bones are present, but the bones themselves don't come through:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the meshes and materials for the eyes and the weapon are present, but they don't have bones and are not connected to the armature.

How can I get Blender to import the bones that correspond to these meshes, with the correct rotation/orientation and connected to the armature and taking part in the animation?